# Variation of free energy vs. order parameter

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, greens-functions, bose-einstein-condensate

In the paper [M. Holzmann, G. Baym, Phys. Rev. B 76, 092502 (2007)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.76.092502) the following formula (Eq. (18)) is given for a Bose-condensed system:
$$
V\delta F=-\frac12\int d\mathbf{r}d\mathbf{r}'\:\delta\langle\Psi(\mathbf{r})\rangle^*G^{-1}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')\delta\langle\Psi(\mathbf{r}')\rangle,
$$
where $\langle\Psi(\mathbf{r})\rangle=(\langle\psi\rangle,\langle\psi\rangle^*)^T$ is the expectation value of the two-component order parameter. So the inverse Green function is the second variation of the free energy with respect to the order parameter.

How to derive this formula? It is unusual to vary the free energy with respect to the order parameter because the latter in not an independent external parameter but an observable. I think some derivation can be done by introducing the sources of $\psi$ and $\psi^+$ into the Hamiltonian, but where can I found any details?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse Green's function is just the Schrödinger operator: $G^{-1}=i\hbar\partial_t -\hat{H}$. So the expression seems like a rather typical to me - e.g., such expressions often appear in the exponents of path integrals.

Varying in respect to the order parameter is a matter of the ensemble that one uses. Again, in Landau theory of phase transitions the order parameter is the independent variable.